# Rails equivalent to django shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

Does rails have an equivalent to `django-admin.py shell`? Preferably even something that I can run on a remote server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. Rails seems to have a [`console`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console) and a `dbconsole` command that are very similar to Django's `shell` and `dbshell`.